# No database selected in mysql from eclipse java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to connect to mysql from eclipse. Firstly, i created table in mysql, then i built path the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.bin.jar. I want to insert some datas to mysql ,but i got this errors what i am doing wrong?

MYSQL

```
Create database readers;
Use readers;

CREATE TABLE reader
(
Name varchar(265),
Surname varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
Capital varchar(255)
);
```

My java code here

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Connect to DB server
            Connection connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?readers=true","ro‌​ot","password");

            System.out.println("Connected to MySQL");

            //Create Prepared Statement
            PreparedStatement statement =
                    connection.prepareStatement("insert into readers (Name,Surname,City,Capital) values(?,?,?,?)");
```

Errors

```
Connected to MySQL
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
    at edu.sabanciuniv.ReadWriteThread.run(ReadWriteThread.java:57)
```

I searched every question here ,but did not find any solution for my problem. It is not duplicated, the answer in that question not is my solution. I wrote my database name which is "readers" to the getConnection part.

Comment: Maybe not the cause, but your SQL statement has a mistake. It mentions the name of your database "readers", instead of your table name "reader".

Answer (score 2):

The [MySQL Connector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) is pretty clear on the syntax of the connect string:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]] [?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

You have not specified the database name, so the driver does not know to which database to direct the prepared statement.

Comment: For example, i did      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?readers=true","root","password"); My database name is readers i specified it now ,but nothing change. @jim-garrison

Comment: Read the connect string syntax _carefully_. You gave the database name in the wrong place.